# 'reboot' command doesn't work properly after 'cp' command

Tags: linux, cp, reboot, mv

I have compiled C code running as a binary on an ARM.  The ARM boots Linux from an SD Card using an old `Image` that was generated using buildroot.  Within the C code I call a shell script that moves the new `Image` I want to boot with from a sub-directory on the SD Card onto the top level of the SD Card (overwriting the old `Image`), and then use the backup `Image.bak` to restore the `Image` in the sub-directory again, in case I run the script again:

```
#!/bin/sh
mv /sd/newImage/Image /sd/
mv /sd/newImage/Image.bak /sd/newImage/Image
reboot
```

The reboot works properly in this case (Putty disconnects -> the LED on the board I'm using goes Red then Green -> I can reconnect through Putty), although the second `mv` command does not - it removes the `Image.bak` but does not create an `Image` - but that is not the purpose of this post, really.

When I try to modify the script so that the `Image.bak` does actually restore the `Image` by using the `cp` command, then the reboot does not work properly.

```
#!/bin/sh
mv /sd/newImage/Image /sd/
cp /sd/newImage/Image.bak /sd/newImage/Image
reboot
```

What happens is the Putty terminal I was using disconnects, but the LED on the board that goes red when signaling it is rebooting just stays green and the only way to re-establish a connection through Putty is to manually power cycle the board via the power switch.  So it seems that there is something weird happening when I call the `cp` command in the shell script.  I have tried unmounting the SD Card thinking that maybe there was syncing issues, but that didn't work either.

I am logged in as root, and the permissions should not be an issue with any of this.

Comment: You could try to add `sync` before the reboot. Maybe the move command hasn't finished yet.

Answer (score 2):

First, this is actually a systems question, not a programming question, so it should likely be in another stack.

Second, this is quite likely the result of the image actually being a symbolic link to somewhere else in the filesystem.  When you use `cp`, it will replace the content that the link points to.  When you use `mv`, it puts this file into the place of the symbolic link, but leaves the original file unchanged in its actual location.

To verify this, just use `ls -l /sd` and take note of the file type of `Image` (the first character in the attributes).

Comment: Thank you for that.  What other stack should I put this in?  I am new to stackexchange and asking questions like this online.  Also, which column is the attributes? And how would you suggest I change the script to do what I actually want it to do?

Comment: I think it's "server fault" perhaps?

Comment: Oh, sorry.. Missed your other questions.  The very first column is the file attributes.  If it's the letter `l`, then it's a soft link.  If it's just a dash, then my answer is wrong. :)  How to change the script depends on what you find.  If  it is a link, use `mv` to move the file to the actual location of the file (where the link goes).

Comment: All of things in column one either start with a 'drwxr...' or a '-rwxr...'
The Image has a '-rwxr...'

Comment: Well, perhaps more documentation reading, then.  Verify that you need only copy the file to that location to update before booting